# Getting laravel & phpunit to send message when unit test fails

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, laravel-4

I am using a function that tests for existence of an array in each page.  I am using laravel's function `assertViewHas`.  This would be fine if I had a function for each page testing for this array existence, however it seems  waste of time, when I could just have a `foreach` running the test for each page.  However, if one of the page's fails the assertion, I won't know which it is, phpunit will just say the test has failed.

So, is there any way of writing the current `$page` in the fail error when running `phpunit` in the command line?

```
....private $guest_pages=array('/','login','signup');

....
    public function testGuestViewsHaveContent ()
{
    foreach ($this->guest_pages as $page) {
        $response = $this->call('GET', $page);
        $this->assertViewHas('content');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echoing [$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) ?

**Edit**:

Duh... OK this does not answer your question, I didn't understand at first.
So, `assertViewHas` comes from Laravel's extending PHPUnit 
`vendor\laravel\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.php` and basically checks if it's a view instance, if it's an array and just `$this->assertEquals` for each value.

`assertEquals` can have a custom message as a third parameter, so what you can do is modify your test, not using `assertViewhas` but `assertEquals` in a similar way as in `assertViewHas` (extending PHPUnit, not Laravel's testcase) and provide your custom message.